# GDB not showing expected output for examining function parameters

Tags: c, assembly, x86, gdb

I have a simple bit of assembly which I am stepping through in GDB. I am unable to share it here, but the current task is to examine the contents of the `char *` parameter in the function.

```
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0xf7efdb14 <__strcmp_sse4_2+4>:      mov    0x4(%esp),%edx
(gdb) x/s $edx
0xf7f979c0:     ""
(gdb) x/s $esp + 4
0xffffd100:     ",\321\377\377\244pUV f\371\367]cUV\200\373\377\377\353g\277\362\222pUV@n\371\367@\332\377", <incomplete sequence \367>
(gdb) ni
198     in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcmp-sse4.S
(gdb) x/s $esp + 4
0xffffd100:     ",\321\377\377\244pUV f\371\367]cUV\200\373\377\377\353g\277\362\222pUV@n\371\367@\332\377", <incomplete sequence \367>
(gdb) x/s $edx
0xffffd12c:     "abcd\n"
```

It's my understanding that the parameter is in the assembly address of the stack pointer, `%esp` plus an offset of 4. This is confirmed in the assembly, but I can't seem to figure out why I can't examine that value directly in GDB. Instead, I can only examine it after it has been moved to the `%eax` register. I would expect the two `x/s` results to print the same thing, but can't find out why they are not equivalent.

Comment: Because you are missing a level of indirection. `edx` did not work because you tried that before the instruction was executed. `p/s *(char**)($esp+4)` should work.

Comment: Thank you @Jester. The original `x/s $edx` was just to show it was empty and then set after the command. The issue was exactly an indirection issue after all. Thanks